# PHPMailer failing after transferring to another server

Tags: php, phpmailer

This is breaking my brain. I have the exact same code on two separate servers. It sends the SMTP mail without issues in one, and it fails in the other. Console is clean. And I have no means to debug anything since I don't know what exactly failed. Can I borrow a pair of eyes?

It's a simple form with a captcha. After it passes or fails, it answers with a success/fail modal. If it's a fail, it stays on the contact page to correct the mistakes and resend. If it passes, it refreshes the screen after closing the success modal.

My Contact page `<head>`:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var request;

            $("#contactForm").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                // Abort any pending request
                if (request) {
                    request.abort();
                }

                // setup some local variables
                var $form = $(this);

                // Let's select and cache all the fields
                var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

                // Serialize the data in the form
                var serializedData = $form.serialize();

                // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
                // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
                // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
                $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

                request = $.ajax({
                    url: "sendContactMail.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: serializedData
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called on success
                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

                    if (response.status == 0) {
                        // Success! Do something successful, like show success modal
                        jQuery.noConflict();
                        $('#successEmail').modal('show');
                    } else {
                        // Oh no, failure - notify the user
                        jQuery.noConflict();
                        $('#failEmail').modal('show');
                    }

                    $( "#failBtn" ).click(function() {
                        jQuery.noConflict();
                        $('#failEmail').modal('hide');
                    });

                    $( "#passBtn" ).click(function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    });

                });

                // Callback handler that will be called on failure
                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // Say you have a <div class="message"></div> somewhere, maybe under your form
                    //$('.message').html('Error: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown)
                });

                // Callback handler that will be called regardless
                // if the request failed or succeeded
                request.always(function () {
                    // Reenable the inputs
                    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Contact Form:

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form margin-alpha-top" method="POST"> 
    <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label" for="inputSubject">Subject</label>
        <input id="inputSubject" name="subject" type="text" class="form__field">
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label" for="inputName">Name *</label>
        <input id="inputName" name="name" type="text" class="form__field" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label" for="inputEmail">E-mail *</label>
        <input id="inputEmail" name="email" type="email" class="form__field" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label" for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
        <input id="inputPhone" name="phone" type="text" class="form__field">
    </div>
    <div class="form__group form-group--extended">
        <label class="form__label form__label--extended" for="inputMessage">Message *</label>
        <textarea id="inputMessage" name="message" class="form__field form__field--extended" rows="6" required=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row captcha">
        <div class="column-xs-12 column-sm-4 column-md-4 xs-center">
        </div>
        <div class="column-xs-6 column-sm-4 column-md-4 xs-center">
            <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />
            <br/>
            <a href="#" id="secureText" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">
                <small>Refresh Image</small>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="column-xs-6 column-sm-4 column-md-4 xs-center">
            <div class="form__group submit-button">    
                <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    class="form__button button button--gamma margin-beta-bottom" 
                    id="btnSubmit">
                    <span class="button__text">Send</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                        
</form>
```

My sendContactMail.php script

```
<?php
session_start();

$msg = '';


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require './mail/PHPMailer.php';
require './mail/Exception.php';
require './mail/SMTP.php';
require './mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();

//Don't run this unless we're handling a form submission
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';                        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'lotusms@outlook.com';              // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                         // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('lotusms@outlook.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('lotusms@outlook.com', 'Luis Silva');


    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
    $subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : null;
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : null;
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;


    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
<div style="width:100%">
<div><label style="color: #044F69; font-weight:bold">Subject:</label> <span>{$_POST['subject']}</span></div>
<div><label style="color: #044F69; font-weight:bold">Email:</label> <span>{$_POST['email']}</span></div>
<div><label style="color: #044F69; font-weight:bold">Name:</label> <span>{$_POST['name']}</span></div>
<div><label style="color: #044F69; font-weight:bold">Phone:</label> <span>{$_POST['phone']}</span></div>
<div><label style="color: #044F69; font-weight:bold">Message:</label> <span>{$_POST['message']}</span></div>
</div>
EOT;

        if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
            $response = [
                'status'=> 1,
                'msg'   => 'CAPTCHA test failed!'
            ];
        } else {
            //Send the message, check for errors
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                // Generate a response in this failure case, including a message and a status flag
                $response = [
                    'status'=> 1,
                    'msg'   => 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.'
                ];
            } else {
                // Generate a response in the success case, including a message and a status flag
                $response = [
                    'status'=> 0,
                    'msg'   => 'Success!'
                ];
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Generate a response in this failure case, including a message and a status flag
        $response = [
            'status'=> 1,
            'msg'   => 'Invalid email address, message ignored.'
        ];
    }
}
// Add the response to the session, so that it will be available after reload
$_SESSION['response'] = $response;

// Finally display the response as JSON so calling JS can see what happened
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

I have this exact same setup running in other sites also working correctly. What am I not seeing? How can it work in one server and not in another?

I know it's not good practice to post real sites here, but if you want to see them passing and failing and maybe it helps you debug some way, you can. This is a Police Department website. Comletely safe.

[Failing site](http://preview.wybpd.org/contact.php) (From a dedicated server I don't control)

[Passing Site](http://wybpd.sitedev.online/contact.php) (From HostGator)

Thank you so much in advance. This is a pro-bono site I donated so I'm limited to how much help I can recruit

Comment: turn on error reporting (verbose) of PHPMailer to track down the problem: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: I did, but it doesn't output anywhere...

Comment: Upvote because PHPMailer is breaking my brain sometimes, too.

Comment: Could it be any kind of firewall issue?

Comment: It can work in one but not another because the environments are different, e.g. different PHP versions, different network access rules, etc. You've got some very mixed-up code here. You're loading the classes from the current PHPMailer release manually, but then you're loading the autoloader from an old version that's no longer needed. You need to check your web server's error logs; if you're getting no output at all, you may be running on a version of PHP that's too old, and it's dying on new syntax, like the namespace aliases.

Comment: It would have been more useful to tell us what is in your logs and what diagnostics you have run than showing us code which you say works in at least one environment. It would have been helpful if you had tried to create a MCVE and put that here instead of the code you did publish. It would have been helpful if you had given some indicaton of the differences between the two environments.

Comment: @symcbean And I would love to provide that to you. But I have no idea of how to produce all of that. You clearly have more experience than me in this area. Had this been a paying client, I would have help from one of my developers. This is a free site. Ifyou give me some guidance, I can post that info.

Comment: @Synchro I will chack on the PHP version that is running on that server as well as your other instructions. As far as the code being messy, yeah, I'd agree. I'd never pretend to be an expert in PHPMail. Their documentations are always extremely vague.

Comment: Precisely which documentation is extremely vague?

Comment: @Synchro Why don't you just furiously downvote the question to express your discontent with my level of experience on PHPMailer and move on. Seriously, if you're not gonna help, why bother? That's what the downvote is for.

Comment: I helped, and you responded by insulting both me and the software which I spend considerable time maintaining, at no cost to you. That's not a great way of going about getting help, especially since you're not even following the basic example provided in the PHPMailer readme. Did you check the logs like I said? Did you read the troubleshooting guide? Did you do what @Blackbam suggested?

Comment: @Synchro I did do what Blackbam suggested but it didn't produce any debugging .text, or .log, or html, or console info. I stil upvoted him becasue his answer would help someone else who has different problems

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had very similar problems with PHP Mailer. First of all we know that it has to do something with the server, as the site works on the dev server, but not within the live server. Most likely the error occurs because ***the SMTP server connection is not working or the SMTP server in the live system rejects your mail request*** (however it is possible that something already goes wrong with your code earlier due to different PHP versions, different variables, different php.ini, ...).

Therefore we have to debug in order to find the problem. Debugging PHPMailer is very well documented: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging

This is how you should try to debug your issue (code shortened):

```
    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';                        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'lotusms@outlook.com';              // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                         // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('lotusms@outlook.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('lotusms@outlook.com', 'Luis Silva');


    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = "...";


    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4; // Lowest level, you may also use 1, 2 or 3
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'text'; // if this does not work, use 'error_log' or even a custom closure

    var_dump($mail);

    $send = $mail->send());

    var_dump($send);
```

If something is wrong you should see the problem in your `var_dump`s or the output created by `SMTPDebug` and `Debugoutput` property instantly.

There are various possible reasons for your problem, the key is to *debug your code in your live environment (but not necessarily on your live site) properly*.

If `$mail->Debugoutput='text';` is not working try `'error_log'` and view the logfile or even write a custom closure for this purpose (see the docs).